# rviz segmentation fault on launch in electric

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running electric with 10.04, I get the following:

xxxxx@ubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz

rviz revision number 1.6.4ng with size 1 x 1

ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2

compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)

Loading general config from [/home/xxxxx/.rviz/config]

Loading display config from [/home/xxxxx/.rviz/display_config]

RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.

Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1

Segmentation fault

I have done some searching here on answers without anything working for me. The suggestion is that you should just remove .rviz/display_config, however one doesn't exist in the first place. So guys and gals, what should I do? I would rather not install diamondback. There was suggestions that that still works. This should work under electric.

Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11566/rviz-segmentation-fault-on-launch-in-electric/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this post will help you [RViz in ROS electric](http://answers.ros.org/question/2109/rviz-in-ros-electric#3609)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-10-19**:
Hi, thanks. I came across this post before, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a very similar problem at one point. Deleting the entire .rviz directory in my home directory (not just .rviz/display_config) solved my problem.
I also had the same problem running rviz in a VM, but in that case it was related to how the VM allowed access to the video card, and so couldn't be solved.

---

Originally posted by [akargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/1025/akargol/) with karma: 126 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-10-19**:
I went ahead and installed diamondback to see if it will work, and it does. For my purposes I will stick with diamondback, but this is a bit of a pain in the ass, because it is an on going problem it seems.

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-10-19**:
I tried deleting the entire .rviz and I still get the same segfault. I'll look more into whether it is a VM issue or not, thanks.